# Why does using "sudo" use root user as the context for some operations, and not for others?

Tags: git, sudo

When using `sudo` with `git` commands, i noticed that:

`sudo git push` uses the ssh key of the `root` user. But,

`sudo git commit [etc..]` uses the git author that is configured for the original user account.

Why is this so? How does `sudo` decide what context to do things in?

Comment: Have a look at the output of `sudo env`; maybe some git-related environment variables are defined and used here.

Comment: Why you might need to *ever* run Git as root? No, really, what's the use case? I mean I might envision [some sort of deployment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-users/UC_D5b3f0oE/SQLDJRX1MVEJ) which would require root credentials, but just plain work?

Comment: @kostix, It's for deployment. In production it's most secure for application code to be owned by root, and ran by other users, to guarantee the application cannot modify its own source code.

Comment: @MuratAyfer, I wholehearedly agree! But why then you mention `git push` and `git commit`? They have nothing to do with deployment.

Comment: because I committed code from the server. yes, I did. I am not ashamed.

Answer (score 1):

ssh key, and git author are two different things.

- One is entirely up to ssh, which will always uses the `~/ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`
- The other is managed by git, and will be the one mention in `git config user.name`, unless there is a `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` environment variable.
  And that whether or not `sudo` is used.

`git config user.name` and the '`env`' are the two settings you need to check when determining with author is used during a commit. `sudo` or not.

Comment: I'd like to point out these environment variables are explained in the [`git(1)` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html).

Comment: @kostix and also in [`git commit-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree.html#_commit_information)